# AWS SDK migration from v1 to v2: How to implement WithSubscriber() correctly?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk, migration

I have someone's legacy code I've come across from AWS SDK v1:

```
TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
    .WithBucketName(bucket)
    .WithKey(filePath)
    .WithTimeout(TIMEOUT)
    .WithSubscriber(this.uploadFileProgressCallback);
```

I know per [the Amazon v2 Migration docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-migration-guide-v2.html) that the first three attributes should be rewritten as:

```
TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
 {
     BucketName = bucket,
     Key = filePath,
     Timeout = TIMEOUT
 }
```

However, they don't mention anything about `WithSubscriber()`.

I do, however, see an event called `UploadProgressEvent`, which I'm guessing I should be able to subscribe to as:

```
request.UploadProgressEvent += this.uploadFileProgressCallback;
```

However, I don't see this officially documented anywhere.

So, question: Can someone confirm this is the correct way to implement this in v2, or point me to a doc to back it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct,

```
 request.UploadProgressEvent += this.uploadFileProgressCallback;
```

is the right way to set up the progress event callback. Check out the source in [Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/AWSSDK_DotNet35/Amazon.S3/Transfer/TransferUtilityUploadRequest.cs#L321). We will get our documentation updated soon.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, and also for being part of a development team that answers questions on StackOverflow for their product. Made me happy as a developer and a customer at the same time!